# The meaning of Pan-India Character?

Tags: ancient-history

What is meant by the Pan-India Character during the Mauryan Empire at the time of Chandagupta Maurya ?

Comment: Can't tell you what is meant unless you provide a citation/reference.  Where is this term mentioned.

Comment: It is in this line "Pan-India Character: The Mauryan was a vast with all-India character."

Answer (score 1):

The  [Mauryan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurya_Empire), if we look at this map, covered a large region:

[image]

and the word pan- can  be [defined as](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pan-):'"all, every, whole, all-inclusive'

so, Pan-India is indicating the fact that this empire literally covered *all* of the Indian region:

> The Maurya Empire was one of the largest empires of the world in its
>   time. At its greatest extent, the empire stretched to the north along
>   the natural boundaries of the Himalayas, to the east into Assam, to
>   the west into Balochistan (south west Pakistan and south east Iran)
>   and the Hindu Kush mountains of what is now Afghanistan.[7] The Empire
>   was expanded into India's central and southern regions[8][9] by the
>   emperors Chandragupta and Bindusara

The 'Character' aspect of the phrase may again relate to the definition, the 'all-inclusive' part. Again from the Wiki :

> Mauryan India also enjoyed an era of social harmony, religious
>   transformation, and expansion of the sciences and of knowledge.
>   Chandragupta Maurya's embrace of Jainism increased social and
>   religious renewal and reform across his society...

Comment: Actually, it's a little subtler than that. An empire with pan-Indian character would have a culture and characteristics drawn from all the regions of India. It *isn't* an empire whose ruling class are all from one region and thus rule in a manner characteristic of that region.

Comment: Noted. Added some on the social aspect, the original question didn't really give enough context to me for a good determination of intent, however.